# Change dropdowns with same .class name

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have three dropdowns with same class name:

```
<select class="MyClass">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select class="MyClass">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<select class="MyClass">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

I want to change any of these dropdown values based on any other dropdrop selected. If I select option two from second dropdown - I want 1st and 3rd dropdown values to be two. All these dropdown should change values no matter which one I select.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need JavaScript to do this. Here is an code example using jQuery:

```
$('.MyClass').on('change',function(){
    $('.MyClass').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

This will add an EventListeneer for the change Element and update all DropDowns to the value of the changed one.

http://jsfiddle.net/CWP7Q/

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery or normal JS, but my example contains Jquery, which will give you an idea. Please check the example in [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P2Djw/).

The example binds a change event to the class name of the three selectors:

```
$(".MyClass").change(function(){
    $(".MyClass").val($(this).val());
});
```

and Voila, every selector gets changed.

Answer (score 1):

Somehting like (with jQuery)

```
$('.MyClass').change(function() {
    $('.MyClass').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Thanks. It works with static dropdowns however I'm creating the 2nd and 3rd dropdown dynamically using a button click. The solution above is not firing for dynamically created dropdowns. Any suggestions?

Comment: refer to JaGo answer, it should work. `on` method works on dynamically added content